# tf.nn.conv2d in numpy or scipy (with 4-d weights)?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy

For part of an embedded project, I trained a network in Tensorflow, and now I'm reloading the variables in a Numpy/Scipy-based model script. However, I am unclear on how to redo the conv2d steps with the weights I have.

I've looked at this link: [Difference between Tensorflow convolution and numpy convolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853767/difference-between-tensorflow-convolution-and-numpy-convolution),
but I haven't made the connection to a problem where the weights are four-dimensional.

This is my Tensorflow code:

```
# input shape: (1, 224, 224, 1)

weight1 = tf.Variable([3,3,1,16],stddev)
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input,w,[1,1,1,1])

# conv1 shape: (1, 224, 224, 16)

weight2 = tf.Variable([3,3,16,32],stddev)
conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv2,w,[1,1,1,1])

# conv2 shape: (1, 224, 224, 32)
```

And when I try to use convolve functions from Scipy or Numpy libraries, the output dimensions are incorrect:

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve

conv1 = convolve(input, weight1[::-1])

# conv1 shape: (1, 224, 224, 1)

conv2 = convolve(conv1, weight2[::-1])

# conv2 shape: (1, 224, 224, 16)
```