# Convolution on numpi vs tensorflow 2.4

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am very new to Tensorflow 2.4 and I have a question.

let x = [3, 4, 5],　h = [2, 1, 0]

using numpy I get

np.convolve(x, h) = [6, 11, 14, 5, 0]

but I have no idea to do this via tensorflow 2.4

It would be very helpful if you know how to do this and get the same result with numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I think this question is mostly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853767/difference-between-tensorflow-convolution-and-numpy-convolution), I can use that question to come up with an equivalent script.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

I = [3, 4, 5]
K = [2, 1, 0]

I = [0] + I + [0]

i = tf.constant(I, dtype=tf.float32, name='i')
k = tf.constant(K, dtype=tf.float32, name='k')

data   = tf.reshape(i, [1, int(i.shape[0]), 1], name='data')
kernel = tf.reshape(k, [int(k.shape[0]), 1, 1], name='kernel')

res = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv1d(data, kernel[::-1], 1, 'SAME'))
print(res)
print(np.convolve(I, K, 'SAME'))
```

> tf.Tensor([ 6. 11. 14.  5.  0.], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)

> [ 6 11 14  5  0]

In your situation, they key is to understand how tensorflow and numpy treat padding. Although the linked question does a good job of explaining this, I would also note the fact that the default [np.convolve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) padding of `full` does not have an equivalent in the tensorflow conv 1d.